# How to save R subfiles into a specific folder?

Tags: r, file, save

I would like to save subfiles into a specific folder that was created just before.

I don't show the whole script but this script will be executed several times later. That's why I create a specific directory thanks to the `dir.create()` function with the date and the hour.

And then, I want to put the subfiles generated by the script into this specific directory but I don't know how to manage the `save` function to get what I want.

The names of my subfiles will be : submatrix_1.RData , submatrix_2.RData ....

```
dir.create(file.path("~/coefficient_rho", format(Sys.time(), "%F, %H:%M:%S")))

save(res, file=sprintf("~/coefficient_rho/submatrix_%s.RData", opt$subset))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the new folder name first. Then you can just use `file.path` to create your required path.

```
new_fol <- file.path("~/coefficient_rho", format(Sys.time(), "%F, %H:%M:%S"))
if(!dir.exists(new_fol))
  dir.create(new_fol)
fname <- file.path(new_fol,
                   sprintf("submatrix_%s.RData", opt$subset))
save(res,file=fname)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. And in another R script, I need to get these subfiles back to work on them. Is it possible to get them back without specify the name of the directory? I mean, when I execute the other R script, the subfiles are "found" automatically , according to the date to which the directory was created?

Comment: For reading an arbitrary number of files, use `dir` to get the file list and then loop through them